# Android Studio: Unregistered VCS root detected

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Unregistered VCS root detected
           The directory /Users/*****/AndroidStudioProjects/Signin/google-services is under Git, but is not registered in the Settings.
           Add root  Configure  Ignore
How to resolve this?
Please help.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Press "add root" when the warning message appears.

This will make idea register the "unregistered vcs root", and you can use the git features of IDEA/Android studio. Nothing bad will happen if you do not press "add root", but I suspect you will get the same warning on each startup of android studio/IDEA.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between pressing `Ignore` and `Add Root`?

Comment: the warning message is dealt with, but not the reason for the warning message. this really should not be counted as an answer until it addresses at least one reason why you might _not_ want to do that.

Comment: What exactly happens when you push `Add Root` and where are these settings and in which file(s)?

Answer (score 22):

You are able to ignore that warning if you are not interested in using Android Studio's git integration.  Or, you can enable git integration under the VCS | Enable Version Control Integration menu.

Comment: That's all right. But why does the message appear in the first place. What does it mean by "unregistered VCS root"?

Comment: @Virus AS sees that there is a .git directory (or other version control files) in your project and is trying to be helpful be letting you know that you can manage your repo inside android studio, but that it hasn't been enabled. It seems to be a check that is performed each time you open the project.  If you don't want to see it, you can do "add root" as suggested by the other answer, which will make the message disappear for good and enable integration in the IDE, which doesn't do harm even if you don't use it.

Answer (score 20):

VCS stands for "Version Control System", aka "undo on steroids".  No programmer should be without it.

IDEA (which Android Studio is based on) sees some signs in your project directory that your project source is set up to use a Version Control System.

In this case, the VCS in use is git.  The sign is the presence of a projectdir/.git subdirectory.

That indicates that you either created this project directory by "cloning" this project from a git repo:

$ git clone https://github.com/projectname/reponame.git

Or that you created your own git repo in the project directory, by cd'ing to the projectdir and running the command:

/path/to/projectdir $ git init-db

By clicking "add root" you tell IDEA to add this git repo to IDEA's internal settings for the project, so you can use the IDEA features that support using git.  I recommend using it, it won't interfere with your ability to use git from the command line, but some of the IDEA git features are handy.

If you don't know/use git, I highly, highly recommend that you learn it.  It will make your life a lot easier, in the long run.  As I said, it's like "undo" on steroids.

If you already know how to use git, here are a few of IDEA's git features.

The niftiest feature is that you can select a few lines of code, right-click and select Git/Show History for Selection.

The most useful feature (to me) is Alt-9 aka View/Tool Windows/Version Control.

This brings up the version control window, a pane across the bottom of the
IDEA gui.

By default the Version Control Window just shows "Default" (in bold)
and "Unversioned Files".

Expand "Default" to see the files that changed.

Expand "Unversioned Files" to see any files that need to be added to git.

The color indicates the status, all configurable of course, the default config is that blue indicates changed, green indicates added, etc.

Right-click/Show Diff on a changed file and it gives you a nice visual
diff, sort of reminiscent of Meld's UI, which is one of my favorite,
because it uses these sort of cartoon "word ballon" indicators for
each difference, to illustrate where the difference would be in the
other version.

Also, the side of the visual diff that shows the current file appears
to be a fully functional (or mostly functional) IDEA editing window,
making it easy to fix any gratuitous differences.

Some useful related links:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/file-status-highlights.html?origin=old_help

Also, at the same site see:

Howto/General Guidelines/Version Control with Intellij IDEA/VCS-Specific Procedures/Using Git Integration/Checking Git Project Status

Reference/Version Control Reference/File Status Highlights

I'd include links directly to these but apparently stackoverflow doesn't trust me yet.

Answer (score 13):

You can disable Android Studio git integration and get rid of the annoying warning. Here's how with Android Studio 2.1.1 for the Mac OS X:

1. Menu -> "Android Studio/Preferences...".
2. In Preferences window: Click on to open "Plugins"
3. In the Plugins frame: uncheck "Git
   Integration".

Disabling "Git Integration" also disables GitHub, Google Cloud Testing, Google Cloud Tools Core, Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio plugins. (good riddance). By default, Android Studio enables all plugins at install time even though most devs will use only 10% of them.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Developers need to stop treating users as idiots and give them an option to opt out of their so called "cool" features. Less of "Not now", more of "No thanks"

Answer (score 12):

**FIRST STEP:** Click in configure link.

[image]

**SECOND STEP:** then select the correct and add

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you see this message whenever you open Android Studio and create a new project, It's because your projects home directory is set as a VCS root. Maybe It was a mistake, set by you unintentionally. That was my case.

#### To solve it.

Just delete .git directory from projects home directory.

#### Delete: ../AndroidStudioProjects/.git

Comment: This directory (AndroidStudioProjects/.git) doesn't even exist. If you mean a `.git` inside a project, it's not a good idea.