# Unregistered VCS Root Detected message reappears

Tags: android-studio, version-control

My Android Studio project is under VCS (git) control, but (almost) every time I re-open the project, the message appears. I press Add Root (or configure and choose Unregistered Root). VCS works fine for the session, but I will have to Add Root the next time the project is opened.

This is not quite the same as [Android Studio: Unregistered VCS root detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33007835/android-studio-unregistered-vcs-root-detected)

In that case it was a one time set-up.

How can I make my configuration persist?

I am using Android Studio 1.5.1 on Ubuntu 15.04. gitk and git gui show everything to be good.

Comment: I have the same problem on a Debian distro, Did you solved it?

Comment: Same for me using Android Studio 3.2.1; every time I load the projects.  I have tried "Add root" and "configure"; no change, I'm still prompted.