# How to change Unregistered VCS root detected directory

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea

When I create a new project in Android Studio on the Mac the VCS prompt does not include the sub-directory of the new project.

For example, the unregistered VCS root detected prompt:
The directory **/Users/myname/AndroidStudioProjects** should be **/Users/myname/AndroidStudioProjects/NewProject** is under Git but is not registered in the Settings.

Anyone knows the fix for this? As a work around I cancel this prompt, go into the VCS tab, import into VCS, and enter the correct directory.

Comment: Related post - [Android Studio: Unregistered VCS root detected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33007835/465053)

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same issue.

Seems Jetbrain's IDE'S like IntelliJ-IDEA (or Android Studio) are only looking for descendant directories of the project-root to find further **unregistered VCS roots**.

[Adding the VCS roots manually](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-cvs-roots.html) to the Settings is really cumbersome.

AFAIK, there is no specific setting (indexing-level, automatic scan) to set or fix that, which changes the behavior. (at least not at the moment) But I have a little time saving workaround:

The VCS roots are always saved in your `project-root/.idea/vcs.xml` file.

**Workaround:**

What I usually do is, I just **copy (or clone) the sub-projects into a descendant directory** of my project-root *(ie. /packages)*, which will prompt me the "unregistered VCS roots" balloon, where I then can **hit "add roots"** then.
Next I **move the sub-projects into the desired destination**. **Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>**, and **search for `vcs.xml`** (have to type it completely), which will get you where the added roots have been saved to. A last **Find & Replace** and **append the missing part of the destination directory**.

I also keep a backup after I've edited the `project-root/.idea/vcs.xml` file, for situations where I require the same sub-projects to be in my VCS roots, so I don't have to repeat this again.

I hope Jetbrains will fix to also include sub directories, which goes deeper that one level of the project-root. This whould be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a VCS Root to your project

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/configuring-cvs-roots.html